# Statistical podcasts

Tags: references

What are some podcasts related to statistical analysis?  I've found some audio recordings of college lectures on ITunes U, but I'm not aware of any statistical podcasts.  The closest thing I'm aware of is an operations research podcast [The Science of Better](http://www.scienceofbetter.org/podcast/).  It touches on statistical issues, but it's not specifically a statistical show.

Comment: A number of possibly useful podcasts have been posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/data-science-podcasts.

Comment: Many of the podcasts mentioned in the answers are no longer active. A dynamic list is present here - https://dspods.netlify.app/. It's a helpful resource for anyone looking for some interesting stats/data science podcast. Disclaimer: I am the creator of this website.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

BBC's [More or Less](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/programmes/more_or_less/default.stm) is often concerned with numeracy and statistical literacy issues.  But it's not specifically about statistics.  Their [About](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/programmes/more_or_less/1628489.stm) page has some background.

> More or Less is devoted to the powerful, sometimes beautiful, often abused but ever ubiquitous world of numbers.
>     The programme was an idea born of the sense that numbers were the principal language of public argument.
>     [...]

Answer (score 7):

There is [econtalk](http://www.econtalk.org/), it is mostly about economics, but delves very often to issues of research, science, and statistics.

Comment: Econtalk is one of the most intelligent podcasts out there.

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested in the following link: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/seminars/ where the UCLA Statistical Computing unit of the UCLA has *very nice* screen-casts available. I have found them very useful in the past. They function essentially as lectures. Top-quality teaching.

Comment: And probably not easily put on an iPod, if that is essential to you.

Comment: No, although there are plug-ins (for Firefox, at least) that help with downloading Flash.  Not easy in all cases, but possible in most.

Answer (score 5):

Another good podcast is [In our time](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/features/in-our-time/) by the BBC. It's a weekly podcast (off air for the summer) that deals with topics in History, Religion and Science. I would say that about 1 in 12 podcasts deal with Mathematics and Statistics. Take a look at the podcast archive for [Science subjects](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/features/in-our-time/archive/science).

Answer (score 4):

Check out my podcast
[Www.learningmachines101.com](http://www.learningmachines101.com)
Which covers topics in statistical
Machine learning

Answer (score 3):

I also just realized the [freakonomics has a podcast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/freakonomics-radio/id354668519)

Comment: It's a lovely podcast that I can strongly recommend but it doesn't deal that much with statistics. I've found the [Radiolab](http://www.radiolab.org/) also has some statistics - their show about [stochasticity](http://www.radiolab.org/2009/jun/15/) is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Keith Bower has a number of statistics related podcasts.  They're pretty good and helps get the concepts down.  You can get them on iTunes or his website: keithbower.com.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't listened to the most recent episodes, but I find the talking machines: http://www.thetalkingmachines.com/ to be really good. it's done by Pr. Ryan Adams and reporter Katherine Gorman.

Answer (score 2):

Not So Standard Deviations (https://soundcloud.com/nssd-podcast)

Answer (score 0):

[Simply Statistics](http://simplystatistics.org/) is a blog about statistics and has several podcasts: http://simplystatistics.org/category/podcast/

From there [about](http://simplystatistics.org/about/):

> We are three biostatistics professors (Jeff Leek, Roger Peng, and Rafa Irizarry) who are fired up about the new era where data are abundant and statisticians are scientists.
>
> Why “Simply Statistics”: We needed a title. Plus, we like the idea of using simple statistics to solve real, important problems. We aren’t fans of unnecessary complication -- that just leads to lies, damn lies and something else.

Answer (score 0):

A podcast about using R doing statistics: http://www.r-podcast.org/